# how to find items having multiple "has_many through" relations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with many-to-many relationships implemented using "has_many through: relationships.  For example

Car has_many :features, though: :feature_associations

I have a list of cars (VIN1, VIN2, VIN3), and a list of features, "4-door", "6 cylinder", "DVD Player", "GPS", "Bluetooth Audio", ...

Each car can have multiple features (through feature associations that tie them together).

Now, I am trying to search for cars having multiple features.  I want to find cars that have both "GPS" and "4-door" features.

So far, I have found a query that will give me cars with any (OR) of the features, but I want all of the features (AND)

```rb
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feature_associations
  has_many :cars, through: :feature_associations
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feature_associations
  has_many :features, through: :feature_associations
end

class FeatureAssociation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :car
end

Car.includes(:feature_associations,:features).references(:features).where( features: { name: ["4-door","GPS"] })
```

The above returns all cars that have 4-doors or GPS, but I am looking for all the cars that have both.

Comment: What about adding a second `where` query? 
`Car.includes(:feature_associations,:features).references(:features).where( features: { name: '4-door' }).where(features: { name: 'GPS' })`

Comment: I tried that, and got zero results. I think it is filtering the join, and each line in the join has either one feature or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, but it's not very "activerecord-y".

```rb
list = []
Car.includes(:feature_associations,:features).references(:features).where( features: { name: "4-door" }).each do |k| list << k.id end

Car.includes(:feature_associations,:features).references(:features).where(id: list).where( features: { name: "GPS" })...
```

This takes one query per feature selected; so it feels like I could have done worse.  On the other hand, there is probably a "right way to do it", and I highly doubt this is it.

Do you have a better way?  (Please?)